# Can I use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for multiple fields?

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL insert statement that looks something like this?

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO profile_answers (user_id, profile_id, question_id, question_answer, timestamp) VALUES ($user_id, $profile_id, {$i}, $answer, NOW())";
```

This is called three times, each time altering the question ID but the user_id and profile_id are the same.  Is it possible to prevent duplicate entries using 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE by first looking at the first two fields (user_id, profile_id)?

A entry in my DB would look like this:

```
user_id profile_id  question_id
5           7                 1
5           7                 2
5           7                 3
```

Is it possible to prevent a second insert of ( 5, 7, 1) for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter table profile_answers add unique index(user_id, profile_id, question_id);
```

This will prevent inserting the same values twice for these columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `UNIQUE` index covering all three columns. This will trigger the `ON DUPLCATE KEY UPDATE` clause.